# Таймер для FireFox

Tags: таймер

как сделать в этом коде, чтобы таймер показывался но при этом не исчезало название самой

вкладки,можно как-то так сделать?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @include *
// ==/UserScript==

start=(new Date()).getTime();
window.setInterval(function(){
   document.title=Math.floor(((new Date()).getTime()-start)/1000);
}, 340);
```

Answer (score 2):

Т.к. время вы отображаете в секундах. менять `title` чаще раза в секунду смысла нет

```
defTitle=document.title;
startTime=new Date().getTime(); 
setInterval(function(){
    document.title=defTitle+' - '+Math.round((new Date().getTime()-startTime)/1000);
}, 1000);
```

вообще если такие вопросы вызывают траблы - программирование нужно хоть чуть подтянуть